# Computer realisation of automorphism group of polyhedron

Tags: combinatorics, polyhedra

I have a polyhedron (I am especially interested in the case of Platonic solids) and the graph corresponding to its skeleton. I also have some data associated with this graph (e.g. different colourings, different sets of weights of edges and so on).

The automorphism group of the polyhedron acts on this data, and I want to find the orbits of this action. 
It seems to me that the problem is too complicated to solve it by hand, so I want to do it via computer.

Are there any solutions which would make me closer to the result than if I just start to code the whole thing in C++ from scratch?

Thanks in advance.